# View Current Month Name as the first Row at top of worksheet whenever it re-opens

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I open the worksheet, I wish the current Month name row to be adjusted at the top of worksheet.

I entered month name in cell E2-January, then after 115 rows again cell E117-February and continue the naming with same interval. As it requires everyday entries and rechecks, the current month might be scrolled up or down.

Is it possible to have the current month Name row at the top whenever I open this worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `Workbook_Open`: Scroll to Current Month's Row

- Copy the code into the `ThisWorkbook` module.
- Whenever you open the workbook, it will select the worksheet and scroll accordingly.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Const WorksheetName As String = "GA"
    Const RowOffset As Long = 115
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = Worksheets(WorksheetName) _
        .Range(FirstCellAddress).Offset((Month(Date) - 1) * RowOffset)
    
    Application.Goto FirstCell, True
    
End Sub
```

- If you want to scroll whenever the worksheet is activated, then use the following in the sheet module `Sheet2(GA)`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    
    Const RowOffset As Long = 115
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell =  _
        Range(FirstCellAddress).Offset((Month(Date) - 1) * RowOffset)
    
    Application.Goto FirstCell, True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I have 3 work sheets with this workbook. I want this set up in sheet 2. The sheet 2 tab is named as GA. How the code can it be then ? I am not much familiar with VBA, excuse me please.

Comment: Instead of "Sheet1" use "GA".

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008
Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. I tried the code after insert a module with GA sheet and then with ThisWorkbook itself. I scrolled down to December, then reopen anticipating March row will come, but not happened

Comment: You don't insert a module, the appropriate modules are already in the workbook and they are called `ThisWorkbook` and `Sheet2(GA)`. Open `VBE>View>Project Explorer` and double-click on your project (`VBAProject(YourWorkbookName.xlsm)`) and double-click the desired module and copy the code to it.

Comment: Yes , now it changes, but every time it rearrange to row 117, but in that row I have Feb month. I need it dynamic, means it should show the Current month row even though i scroll down to December, when i reopen the tab i am expecting it would show the current month  March, row

Comment: Excuse VBasic 2008, I mistakenly thought the current month is March. Expect it will change it’s row positioning accordingly the month changes, highly Grateful